# Complete statement in Visual Studio (2015) with a semicolon at the end and a newline

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

With automatic brace completion in place it would be nice to automate the `<end>-';'-<enter>` with *one* shortcut (also to save the trouble for the little finger), for instance to end the statement after one types 'c' in `Somefunction(AnotherFunction(a * (b + c)))`.

There are solutions for C# (VS Productivity Tools, ReSharper) as mentioned in http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/02/23/useshiftenter/ while I am yet to find any for **C++**.

Since macros are removed starting from VS2012, I wonder if there is an alternative to accomplish this without having to write an extension *yourself*?

Comment: There's https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/ Though if that's what you're after this is a tool request and therefore off topic.

Comment: I am using ReSharper C++ and it is a great tool, but the desired feature is only available in ReSharper (for C#)!

Comment: ..Unless many others have the same problem and it is possible to put it in place without having to write a plugin (but of any such facilities I am not aware) only then it shall be a tool request. ;)

Comment: Send a feature request to Jetbrains. The C++ product is still pretty new, and just recently got the "disable once with comment" feature (to suppress warnings) that C# had but C++ didn't.

Comment: You can use Visual Commander for macros code in VS 2015.

Comment: A Shift+Enter shortcut for End then ; would make typing every line of code easier in C++ or C#.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson for C++ default shortcut is Shift + **Ctrl** + Enter and then sometimes (or quite often) an extra newline is not particularly wanted :/. EDIT: just tried editing C# and it actually adds ';'. Very kind of you C# programmers but sometimes the greatest features of yours are not available in C++ editor ;).

Comment: Thanks to Sergey, I have Shift+Enter working for C++ (and C#) by recording a macro using his freemium Visual Commander extension for VS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but for me it turned out to be very relevant. I found a similar [page for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143935/whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-in-visual-studio-code-to-complete-statement-like-in). And so far I have not been able to find any extension that would work for Visual Studio 2022.

Using Visual Commander, I wrote a script that solves this problem. He also does some other things. I bound it for keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`, to simulate code completion like Intellij Idea. Maybe this will help someone.

The script successfully handles these situations:
(`|` is a cursor)

```cs
in|t x = (12 + 3)  ====> int x = (12 + 3);
                         |
```

```cs
if (tru|e)  ====> if (true) {
                     |
                  }
```

```cs
while (fals|e) {{}} ====> while (false) {
                              {
                                  |
                              }
                          }
```

```cs
void Foo(int x)|  ====> void Foo(int x) {
                            |
                        }
```

```cs
boo|l Foo(int x)  ====> bool Foo(int x) {
                            return |false; //false will be selected for quick change
                        }
```

**Script**

```cs
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand {
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        EnvDTE.TextDocument doc = DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument") as EnvDTE.TextDocument;
        EnvDTE.EditPoint p = doc.CreateEditPoint();
        p.MoveToLineAndOffset(ts.TopLine, 1);
        string text = p.GetText(p.LineLength);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) {
            StatementConstructor c = new StatementConstructor(text, ts);
            c.Process();
            c.Destroy();
        }
    }

    class StatementConstructor {
        private const char openSymbol_2 = '(';
        private const char openSymbol_4 = '{';
        
        private const char closeSymbol_1 = ']'; private const char closeSymbol_2 = ')';
        private const char closeSymbol_3 = '>'; private const char closeSymbol_4 = '}';
        
        private string rawText;
        private string text;
        private EnvDTE.TextSelection ts;
        
        private int type;
        private string retT;
        
        public StatementConstructor(string text, EnvDTE.TextSelection ts) {
            rawText = text;
            this.text = RemoveClose(text, new char[4] { closeSymbol_1, closeSymbol_2, closeSymbol_3, closeSymbol_4 });
            this.ts = ts;
        }
        
        public void Process() {
            CheckContent();
            
            if (type == 2) FormatMethod();
            else if (type == 1) FormatSyntax();
            else FormatExpr();
        }
        
        private void FormatExpr() {
            ts.GotoLine(ts.TopLine, true);
            ts.Tabify();
            ts.EndOfLine(false);
            ts.Text = ";";
            ts.NewLine(1);
        }
        
        private void FormatMethod() {
            FormatSyntax();
            
            if (retT != null && retT != "void") {
                ts.Text = "return;";
                ts.CharLeft(false, 1);
                ts.Text = " ";
                if (retT == "int" || retT == "double" || retT == "float" || retT == "decimal" || retT == "byte" || retT == "long" || retT == "short" ||
                        retT == "sbyte" || retT == "ushort" || retT == "uint" || retT == "ulong") {
                    ts.Text = "0";
                    ts.CharLeft(true, 1);
                }
                else if (retT == "char") {
                    ts.Text = "' '";
                    ts.CharLeft(true, 3);
                }
                else if (retT == "string") {
                    ts.Text = "\"\"";
                    ts.CharLeft(true, 2);
                }
                else if (retT == "bool") {
                    ts.Text = "false";
                    ts.CharLeft(true, 5);
                }
                else {
                    ts.Text = "null";
                    ts.CharLeft(true, 4);
                }
            }
        }
        
        private void FormatSyntax() {
            int countOpen = GetCount(text, openSymbol_4);
            int countClose = GetCount(text, closeSymbol_4);
            
            if (countClose <= countOpen) {
                int diff = countOpen - countClose;
                ts.GotoLine(ts.TopLine, true);
                ts.Tabify();
                ts.EndOfLine(false);
                
                if (countClose == countOpen) {
                    if (countOpen == 0) {
                        ts.Text = openSymbol_4.ToString();
                        ++countOpen;
                        ++diff;
                        
                        int line = ts.TopLine + countOpen;
                    
                        ts.NewLine(1);
                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < diff; ++i) {
                            ts.NewLine(1);
                            ts.Text = closeSymbol_4.ToString();
                        }

                        ts.GotoLine(line, false);
                        ts.EndOfLine(false);
                    } else {
                        ts.DeleteLeft(countOpen);
                        diff = countOpen;
                        
                        int line = ts.TopLine + countOpen;
                    
                        ts.NewLine(1);
                    
                        for (int i = 0; i < diff; ++i) {
                            ts.NewLine(1);
                            ts.Text = closeSymbol_4.ToString();
                        }

                        ts.GotoLine(line, false);
                        ts.EndOfLine(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    int line = ts.TopLine + countOpen;
                    
                    ts.NewLine(1);
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < diff; ++i) {
                        ts.NewLine(1);
                        ts.Text = closeSymbol_4.ToString();
                    }

                    ts.GotoLine(line, false);
                    ts.EndOfLine(false);
                }
            }
        }
        
        private void CheckContent() {
            if (text.StartsWith("if(") || text.StartsWith("if ") || text.StartsWith("if{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("else(") || text.StartsWith("else ") || text.StartsWith("else{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("for(") || text.StartsWith("for ") || text.StartsWith("for{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("foreach(") || text.StartsWith("foreach ") || text.StartsWith("foreach{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("do ") || text.StartsWith("do{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("while(") || text.StartsWith("while ") || text.StartsWith("while{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("catch(") || text.StartsWith("catch ") || text.StartsWith("catch{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("try ") || text.StartsWith("try{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("using(") || text.StartsWith("using ") || text.StartsWith("using{") ||
                    text.StartsWith("lock(") || text.StartsWith("lock ") || text.StartsWith("lock{")) {
                type = 1;
                return;
            }
            
            string[] test = text.Split(' ');
            string returnT = FindMethod(test);
            if (returnT != null) {
                type = 2;
                retT = returnT;
            }
        }
        
        private string FindMethod(string[] strs) {
            if (strs == null || strs.Length <= 0) return null;

            bool has = false;
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; ++i) {
                string str = strs[i];
                has = CheckMethodName(str);
                if (has) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (has) {
                for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                    string str = strs[i];
                    if (str.Contains("=")) return null;
                }
                return (strs.Length > index - 1 && index - 1 >= 0) ? strs[index - 1] : "void";
            }
            
            return null;
        }

        private bool CheckMethodName(string str) {
            return str.Length > 0 && str[0] != openSymbol_2 && str.Contains(openSymbol_2.ToString());
        }
        
        private string RemoveClose(string str, char[] sub) {
            str = str.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });
            List<char> chars = new List<char>(sub);
            
            int lastIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i) {
                if (!chars.Contains(str[i])) break;
                lastIndex = i;
            }
            
            if (lastIndex == -1) return str;
            
            string target = str.Substring(0, lastIndex + 1);
            string els = str.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Count; ++i) {
                char ch = chars[i];
                target.Replace(ch.ToString(), "");
            }

            return (target + els).Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });
        }
        
        private int GetCount(string input, char sub) {
            int count = 0;
            int index = input.IndexOf(sub);
            while (index >= 0) {
                index = input.IndexOf(sub, index + 1);
                ++count;
            }
            return count;
        }
        
        public void Destroy() {
            ts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The script will work fine in C/C++/C#. You may need to turn on automatic code alignment in the settings.

Probably this script will not satisfy the needs of everyone. But for full auto-completion of lines, syntax analysis is needed. This is clearly not what I would like to do in the near future. In the end, my needs were met.