# What's the keyboard shortcut in visual studio code to complete statement like in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is exist keyboard shortcut to complete statement in current line in visual studio code, like in IntelliJ?

The complete statement is that [Complete Statement](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html), I can enter <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to complete current line smartly.

The visual studio code support this function？

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I searched it before, but there isn't the function I wanted...Seems no native keyboard shortcut support it?

Answer (score 6):

[Complete Statement](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=weakish.complete-statement) will help to some extent.
However, this extension lacks one feature - going inside the block. For example - for a if block if you use the shortcut to autocomplete the statement the cursor will still stay on the same line unlike Jetbrains IDE where it intelligently moves to the correct line.

Those who want to get the same feel as *Jetbrains IDE's complete statement feature* they can customize the keyboard shortcut like this:

*Shortcut 1:* **Ctrl+ Shift+ Enter** (to complete current statement)

*Shortcut 2:* **Ctrl+ Shift** (to go to next line)

It's just some extra keystrokes but still you can at least get it done!

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugins can hardly be compared to the very intuitive `complete statement` function of intellij. When I try to autocomplete inside a `js object`, it just throws a `semi colon` at the end of the line instead of a `comma`

Comment: VS Code Newbie Question: How do I customize those 2 keyboard shortcuts to work ? (For any file type ...)

Comment: I added the Complete Statement plugin mentioned above, but the shortcut `Command-;` didn't work, because the IntelliJ Keyboard Bindings plugin had reserved that for configurations. After removing the IntelliJ Bindings, `Command-;` works.

Answer (score 4):

You probably looking for [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) feature of VSCode.

If you select the language that you coding with it (at right of bottom bar) and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, auto-complete & suggestion menu (according to your selected language) was shown.

**Update:** [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=weakish.complete-statement) for VSCode is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

using [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros),and create:

```
"macros": 
    {
        "end_semicolon": // add ;\n
        [              
            "cursorEnd",
            {
                "command": "type",
                "args": {"text": ";\n"}
            },
            
        ],
 
        "end_colon":  // add :\n\t
        [
            "cursorEnd",
            { 
                "command": "type",
                "args": {"text": ":\n\t"}
            },
        ],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a extension named **[Complete Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NoaT.java-complete-current-statement)**, it must be the way to complete the function you are asking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).